# How would I get the first non-empty cell in a column?

Tags: vba, excel

If a cell is empty, I want it to look in the cell above. If that one is empty, it will look in the cell above that until it finds a non-empty cell. When it does, it should return it. It'll be a UDF called `loopUp`. Then, when I use it in a cell formula like so: `=loopUp(D24)`, and the range D18:D24 is empty, it'll show what is in D17.

Here's some Psuedo:

```
Function loopUp(Cell)
    while Cell is empty
        Cell becomes cell above
    return cell
```

I am new to VBA. The thing I am stuck on is how to pass in the address of a cell rather than its value.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: have you tried writing the function yourself? If so, post what you tried and we can help you with what is not working.

Comment: That's the logic which you added. Can you show the code that you actually wrote and also mention which part is not working...

Comment: `I am stuck on is how to pass in the address of a cell rather than its value` Try like this `Function loopUp(cl as range)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Siddharth's last suggestion, here is a way to tackle it.

```
Function LoopUp(rng As Range) As Variant

Dim intCnt As Long

LoopUp = "Nothing found"

For intCnt = rng.Row To 1 Step -1
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(intCnt, rng.Column)) Then
        LoopUp = Cells(intCnt, rng.Column)
        Exit For
    End If
Next


End Function
```

**UPDATE**

This may be a better, cleaner, easier to understand solution. I tested it a bit, but someone may break it!

```
Function LoopUp(rng As Range) As Variant

If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then LoopUp = rng
Else
    If rng.End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then LoopUp = "Nothing found" Else LoopUp = rng.End(xlUp)
End If 

End Function
```

Comment: + 1 This works. But there is no need for a loop :) @TimWilliams deleted his answer because you and me were asking the OP to show some efforts. His answer is really nice. Hope he undeletes it.

Comment: I didn't see his answer, but see my update. Found a easier, cleaner way, I think. Unless someone can break it!

Comment: I think that returning a meaningful value when the function should return an error is very very wrong, Not that I'd expect the range to contain "Nothing found" in some cell, but as a general principle. And of course your second variant won't work if the cell itself contains a value, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @panda-34. In general, I agree with your first statement, but that is the beauty of VBA (and IFERROR, ISERROR formulas). We can take #VALUE! and turn into something that means something to the eye very easily! Good point about the 2nd variant! I am edited post to fix for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Function LoopUp(rng as Range)
    With rng.Cells(1)
        If Len(.Value) > 0 Then
            Lookup = .Value
        Else
            LoopUp = .End(xlUp).Value
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

EDIT: there was some discussion around what should happen if there's no "non-empty" cell above the passed Range parameter. Since the OP didn't specify what should happen this case this just returns an empty response.

Comment: + 1 I love the simplicity of it :)

Comment: This would be worthwhile? `If Len(Trim(rng.Cells(1).Value)) <> 0 Then LoopUp = rng.Value _
    Else LoopUp = rng.Cells(1).End(xlUp).Value`

Comment: Yes! - I missed the "if a cell is empty" part of the question

Comment: Len(.Value) will be a run-time error if the cell contains an error value and it will break if the cell intentionally contains an empty string, so it's not a good way to test for emptiness. Also it won't work if there're hidden rows with values in the range. End function is intended for interactive movement.

Answer (score 0):

the UDF will look like this:

```
Function loopUp(Cell)
  Do While IsEmpty(Cell)
    Set Cell = Cell.Offset(-1)
  Loop
  loopUp = Cell
End Function
```

Note, that function will be recalculated only when Cell itself is changed and not when you change the range above Cell (which the functions scans), To cope with that add a second dummy parameter which should be set to the range which you want the function to monitor to be recalculated (maybe the whole column for simplicity).

Comment: `Set Cell = Cell.Offset(-1)` will break if gets to the first row and it's empty. Need an error trap for that.

Comment: @Scott What do you mean, 'will break'? The result of calling such a function will be an error, exactly what you'd expect when there's no value to return. Special error handling wasn't requested by OP and as such was left as an exercize.

Comment: Fair enough point from your end, but I was simply making a comment that I felt was worth noting as good programming practice.

Comment: @Scott I consider it a good programming practice not to silently suppress exceptions but let the user know that something went wrong at the level where he can do something about it. In this situation an error trap must be on Excel worksheet with ISERR function. And I really see no need to invent some 'magic value' signifying an error and introducing possible ambiguity when you can use an actual error value provided by Excel (without even writing any code)

Comment: Good point above. I thought about this too after I left the office last night. It's funny though, these seem to be the finer points of programming and how they get implemented are often affected by the scope of the project and who is using it! It's always good to know the options available though.